# SharePoint on-prem list is skipped during migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, sharepoint-administration, sharepointmigrationtool

I'm migrating a SharePoint on-prem list to the SPO list using SharePoint Migration Tool. While the migration list get skipped, below is the message:

"SharePoint on-premise list 'CommentHistory' is skipped; Reason: The list reference is broken. The lookup field 'Status' cannot find the referred list '43a0c2f8-1efe-4acc-b49c-f6bec8f74ab4' (ErrorCode: 0x02010023)"

How to fix this?!

Answer (score 0):

If I migrate the list one by one, the issue can be reproduced.

[image: 31503-image.png]

When I migrate the whole site, no error occurs, so I think that the current SPMT does not support one-to-one list migration that contains lookup columns.

Please try to migrate the whole site includes the source list and target list instead of migrating lists one by one.